# wrap paper-dialog-scrollable with another div

Tags: polymer

I am trying to use `paper-dialog-scrollable` inside `paper-dialog` but with scrollable wrapped by `div`

example code:

```
<paper-dialog>
  <div>
    <div class="loading">Loading</div>
    <paper-dialog-scrolalble> ...dynamic long content... </paper-dialog-scrollable>
  </div>
</paper-dialog>
```

I am loading content with AJAX so it is expected that there will be some loading screen. Using `div.loading` inside `paper-dialog-scrollable` is nonsense because user can scroll through content and loading overlay will be scrolled away (using absolute position). So I had to wrap it in another div which will have height of child and so I can use absolute position on loading div.

The problem is that `paper-dialog-scrollable` is no longer working. It's height is about 60px. So i went to documentation, found that there is a property called `dialogElement` and I set this property do a reference to `paper-dialog`. Nothing happend

The solution is to go to the `paper-dialog-scrollable.html` and inside function rewrite `this.dialogElement = this.dialogElement || this.parentElement;` to `this.dialogElement = this.dialogElement || this.parentElement.parentElement;`

But this is really soo hacky and I should check first parentElement if it has needed behaviors and then parentElement.parentElement... This is not what I want to do.. editing source code. This is all about timing. If you set property `dialogElement` before function `_ensureTarget` is called for the first time, it will work.

To make it work, you have to have setted `dialogElement` before `attached` or `ready` functions inside `paper-dialog-scrollable` are called. But there is no way ho to achiev this. Because even `attached` inside my own element is already too late...

From docs:

> If paper-dialog-scrollable is not a direct child of the element implementing Polymer.PaperDialogBehavior, remember to set the dialogElement:
>
> `<script>
>     var scrollable = Polymer.dom(myDialog).querySelector('paper-dialog-scrollable');
>     scrollable.dialogElement = myDialog;
>   </script>`

Like WTF Polymer team? I am using shadow dom.. How am I able to access `myDialog` when it is like twenty times nested inside shadow roots?

Is there any solution to this timing puzzle?

I am using paper-dialog version 2.0.1

and paper-dialog-scrollable version 2.1.0

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you like to change size of your `paper-dialog` size and `paper-dialog-scrollable` element. Just remove the outer `div` and limit the scrollTarget's width/height through the mixin paper-dialog-scrollable:

```
 paper-dialog paper-dialog-scrollable {
    --paper-dialog-scrollable: {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      width: 60px;
      height: 60px;
    }
  }
```

Comment: the outer div is essential here. and it is causing all the problems. I just need to use default scrolling behavior that is working when there is no outer div. Plus the height is dynamic. It depends on user's screen. But this is something that paper dialog should take care of.